# Live Photo Stream / Photowall

Tags: iphone, icloud, photo-stream

For an event I need pictures displayed on a screen right after they are taken on an iPhone.

I tried doing this with an Apple TV and the photostream view, but the photos take some time to show.

Is there any way to make an live feed of pictures taken with an iPhone? I have an Apple TV and MacBook to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some Applescript code to go with grgarside's Answer

I tested and it works. The code needs to be saved as a **stay open** Application.

When the app is running it will try press the right arrow right. In this code I have set it to ten seconds `return 10` But depending on the length of time you set this could be a little bit of a pain if you switch out of aperture for some reason or want to quit the app.

So I have included a  <kbd>CAPS</kbd>  lock key down detection. Which will quit the App on the next iteration. You don't have to use it but it is there if you need to.

```
  on idle
    if isShiftKeyPressed() then
        -- IF CAPS LOCK IS DOWN THE APP WILL QUIT
        display notification with title "Arrow Right App" subtitle "quiting right Arrow App"
        quit me
    end if
    try
        tell application "System Events"
            tell application process "Aparture"
                key code 124
            end tell
        end tell
    end try
    return 10
end idle

on isShiftKeyPressed()

    return (do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c 'import Cocoa; print Cocoa.NSEvent.modifierFlags() & Cocoa. NSAlphaShiftKeyMask > 1'") is "True"
end isShiftKeyPressed
```

I have tested this in **Aperture** and it worked as grgarside suggested.

Remember to change the line `tell application process "Aparture"` to you application if it is not Aperture.

Comment: Update: change the quit key  from shift key being held down to Caps lock down.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Photo Stream in iPhoto/Aperture/Photos, open the last photo full-screen and have a script repetitively press the right arrow key. This way, as soon as new photos come in, it will be scrolled to.

Comment: I am not at my mac at the moment. But if you have the last imported selected at full screen will that auto update

Comment: @markhunte I don't know about Last Imported (don't know if it counts as imported) but with the Photo Stream album, I have done this before, with Aperture specifically.

Comment: Your right Photo streams do not go into last imported. But I added code to go with your answer. Your idea really works well.